# How to use Firestore object data to populate tableview

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, multidimensional-array, google-cloud-firestore

With the help of some videos I was able to parse my Firestore data into an array of arrays, but now I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to use this data to populate my tableview. 
The idea is to use the 'dow' field for the Sections and the 'workouts' field for the Rows.

If I print the first index of my array, this is the output that I'm getting...

> ```
> [Days(dow: "Tuesday", workouts: [Effortflex.Workouts(workout: "Back")]), ..., ...]
> ```

I feel like I'm missing a step here. Can someone assist me with this please.

```
self.loadData { (Bool) in
                    if Bool == true {
                        print(self.dataArray[0])

                        self.dayCount = self.dataArray.count
                    }
                }


    struct Workouts {
        var workout : String
    }


    struct Days {
        var dow : String
        var workouts : [Workouts]

        var dictionary: [String : Any] {
            return ["dow" : dow]
        }
    }

    extension Days {
        init?(dictionary: [String : Any], workouts : [Workouts]) {
            guard let dow = dictionary["dow"] as? String else { return nil }

            self.init(dow: dow, workouts: workouts)
        }
    }

        //MARK: - Load Data
            func loadData(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()){

                let group = DispatchGroup()

                self.rootCollection.getDocuments (completion: { (snapshot, err) in

                    if let err = err
                    {
                        print("Error getting documents: \(err.localizedDescription)");
                    }
                    else {

                        guard let dayDocument = snapshot?.documents else { return }

                        for day in dayDocument {

                            group.enter()

                            self.rootCollection.document(day.documentID).collection("Workouts").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in

                                var workouts = [Workouts]()

                                guard let workoutDocument = snapshot?.documents else { return }

                                for workout in workoutDocument {
                                    let workoutString = workout.data()["workout"] as! String

                                    let newWorkout = Workouts(workout: workoutString)

                                    workouts.append(newWorkout)
                                }

                                let dayTitle = day.data()["dow"] as! String

                                let newDay = Days(dow: dayTitle, workouts: workouts)

                                self.dataArray.append(newDay)

                                group.leave()
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    group.notify(queue: .main){
                        completion(true)
                    }
                })
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an example that you can use as a basis to be able to use your structure.

Make your array into a list and persist in the scope of your class so that the methods of the tableView can access it. You can transform as follows:

`let dataList = dataArray.flatMap{$0}`

Then use the data to display on the tableView

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    dataList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return dataList[section].workouts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
     return dataList[section].dow
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testcell", for: indexPath)
     cell.textLabel?.text = dataList[indexPath.section].workouts[indexPath.row].workout
     return cell
}
```